My proposed NSF GRFP project was just published; what should I do?
I am applying to NSF GRFP in a few days, and have a Research Statement where I outline a project for my PhD. The project I thought of is highly relevant and based on very new ideas in quantum computing, and have been discussing it with others since July, and so I wrote it up.
I was just looking on the arXiv, and found a paper from a month ago (September) that seems to implement my exact project. They took the exact approach I suggested, but simulated the results in a different way. I suspect that this approach has a flaw in going from simulation to actual experimentation on real quantum computers (that I discuss in my statement), and I immediately reached out to the authors to confirm if they have this flaw. The authors have responded, explained how they got around the flaw I raised, and offered to meet to discuss.
What should I do?
My instinctive thought is to make a footnote or something that explains what happened. Will this ruin my chances of getting accepted? I think I must address this (it would feel dishonest to leave it out), but I am unsure of how to do this.

I have spoken to my professors and other advisors, and they emphasize that NSF GRFP funds the student, not the project. That is to say, they are ok if I don't actually pursue this research problem in my PhD, they just want to see that I have the ability to pose good research problems and outline a good strategy to solving the problem.
I intend to make the submission tonight, and have added the following at the end of the appropriate paragraph in my essay:

(When wrapping up my NSF application, I became aware of the very recent work [...] on arxiv, which implemented [my project] using [this trick]. I am in communication with the authors and will soon meet them to discuss these results and future directions.)

The hope is that the reviewers will see that others thought of the exact same problem and solved it using the same approach as a sign of strength with respect to my research capabilities. Further, it is evidence that my problem is relevant, of interest to others, and publishable.

Sorry, this isn't an answer. Edit your question to add new information. See the help center: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help

@Buffy the question was "what should I do?", and this is my proposal for what I should do. If this is a good/bad idea, people can vote; can you clarify why it's not an answer?

Yes, people can either add an update to the main post or post the update as an answer, so long as the update really is an answer to the question. As David says, I think this is a fair answer.

I'm not a reviewer, but I would hesitate to draw attention to the fact that my project had already been done. Your reviewers will not be experts in your sub-field, and I would suggest it is more likely than not that they will have no idea this has preprint exists (they certainly won't go looking for it).

@AzorAhai-him- I agree that the reviewers will likely not be exerts and won't know about it. However, for intellectual honesty reasons, I feel that leaving it out would not be ok. Further, I think the fact that others are thinking about the same problems and solutions as I am shows that I am a good PhD student to fund (they are not funding the project, they are funding the student).

@DavidRaveh you have given all the best reasons to behave with integrity in this situation. That’s commendable. And then there’s the additional (not particularly honorable, but still valid) reason that having posted your story here using what appears to be your real name, if you proceed to behave unethically by withholding your knowledge of the preprint in your GRFP submission, you expose yourself to some serious criticism in the event that one of the reviewers makes the connection between this post and your proposal…
